# How to access an intent:// from flutter webview

Tags: flutter

I have a subscription form online on a website.
Now I am trying to build a mobile app with flutter.
I want to give my app users the possibility to subscribe as well.
But I don't want to do the form validation in the app, since it can change from time to time.

What I did is create a webview widget in flutter, this worked, untill the very last step.
The last step for a subscription is pay for it.
This can be done with a banking app on the phone, but when I click the link to the banking app from the webview, it throws an error:

net::ERR_UNKNOWN_URL_SCHEME

The link it's trying to reach is: intent://bankieren.ideal.ing.nl/..........

So the problem seems to me this intent...
Is there a way I can make this intent work in the webview?
If not, is there a way I can 'mirror' my web-form so I don't have to validate on 2 different locations (web and app)?

Comment: Have you managed to find a solution?